# pygame displaying variable on screen not working

Tags: python, pygame, simulation

I am using pygame and trying to display the variable i which holds the cycle number in my simulation, the variable does not seem to be displaying, however, no errors are thrown either and the sim runs as though the last 3 lines I added to try display the variable were not there. I have tried to change the color (my background is black) and the position to no avail. The code is as follows:

```
while running:
    try:
        i += 1

        if (exp.round_n > exp.total_rounds):
            running = False


        screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        flag = Box2DWorld.destroy([exp.objs, exp.epucks])
        #PyGameUtils.draw_contacts(screen,exp)
        PyGameUtils.draw_world(screen)
        exp.update(i, config)
        Box2DWorld.step()
        pygame.display.flip()  # Flip the screen and try to keep at the target FPS
        #clock.tick(Box2DWorld.TARGET_FPS)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.set_caption("FPS: {:6.3}{}".format(clock.get_fps(), " " * 5))
        tnr = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
        text = tnr.render(str(i), False, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (3,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the order of the instructions. Update the display at the end of the main loop, after the text is `blit()` to `screen`.

```py
while running:
    try:
        i += 1

        if (exp.round_n > exp.total_rounds):
            running = False


        screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
        flag = Box2DWorld.destroy([exp.objs, exp.epucks])
        #PyGameUtils.draw_contacts(screen,exp)
        PyGameUtils.draw_world(screen)
        exp.update(i, config)
        Box2DWorld.step()

        # pygame.display.flip()  # <---------- delete

        #clock.tick(Box2DWorld.TARGET_FPS)
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.set_caption("FPS: {:6.3}{}".format(clock.get_fps(), " " * 5))
        tnr = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
        text = tnr.render(str(i), False, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text, (3,3))

        pygame.display.flip()  # <---------- insert
```

Note, at the begin of the main loop the display is cleared by `screen.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))`.
Then something is drawn and the display is updated by `pygame.display.flip()`.

But the text is drawn after `pygame.display.flip()`. The next thing what happens after drawing the text, is again the clearing of the display, at the begin of the main loop.
So the text is cleared immediately after is is rendered and draw to the `screen` surface, this causes that the text is never visible.